# Expressing $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$ as $1 - \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, self-learning, telescopic-series

I was reading from ***INTRODUCTION TO ALGORITHM (THIRD EDITION) By Thomas H. Cormen*** and came across Telescoping series in the Appendix A (page 1148). And this was the definition:

For any sequence
$a_0,a_1,...,a_n$

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{(a_k - a_{k+1}) =  a_0 - a_n}$

They then gave an example
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(\frac{1}{k} -  \frac{1}{k+1})$

= $1 - \frac{1}{n}$

Please can someone help me on how they had $1 - \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: try choosing a specific number for $n$-say 7. Now write out the 12 terms (6 differences $\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1})$. Once you've got them written out see if anything can be simplified across the terms. Once you see this for $n=7$ the general pattern should be straightforward.

Comment: Re-group the terms: $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\left( {\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{{k + 1}}} \right)}  = \left( {\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2}} \right) + \left( {\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}} \right) +  \ldots  + \left( {\frac{1}{{n - 2}} - \frac{1}{{n - 1}}} \right) + \left( {\frac{1}{{n - 1}} - \frac{1}{n}} \right) \\= 1 + \left( { - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}} \right) +  \ldots  + \left( { - \frac{1}{{n - 1}} + \frac{1}{{n - 1}}} \right) - \frac{1}{n} = 1 + 0 +  \ldots  + 0 - \frac{1}{n} = 1 - \frac{1}{n}.
$$ You can do the same with the general problem involving $a_k$.

Comment: @Gary after the regroup I can see all the terms will cancel except the first and last term. Thank you

Comment: @EALehn Great! Yes, that is the point.

Comment: @EALehn FYI, see [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).